# mysql query with group by or join

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 tables:

```
   categories
    +----+----------------+
    | ID | name           |
    +----+----------------+
    |  1 | First category |
    |  2 | Second category|
    |  3 | Third category |
    +----+----------------+
    subcategories
    +----+----------+----------------+
    | ID | category | name           |
    +----+----------+----------------+
    |  1 |        1 | 1.1 subcategory|
    |  2 |        1 | 1.2 subcategory|
    |  3 |        1 | 1.3 subcategory|
    |  4 |        2 | 2.1 subcategory|
    |  5 |        2 | 2.2 subcategory|
    |  6 |        2 | 2.3 subcategory|
    |  7 |        3 | 3.1 subcategory|
    |  8 |        3 | 3.1 subcategory|
    |  9 |        3 | 3.3 subcategory|
    +----+----------+----------------+
```

I need a single query, that will give result like this:

```
Array( [0] => Array ( [category] = First category, [subcategory] => Array( [0] => "1.1 subcategory", [1] => "1.2 subcategory", [2] => "1.3 subcategory")), [1] => Array ( [category] = Second category, [subcategory] => Array( [0] => "2.1 subcategory", [1] => "2.2 subcategory", [2] => "2.3 subcategory")), [2] => Array ( [category] = Third category, [subcategory] => Array( [0] => "3.1 subcategory", [1] => "3.2 subcategory", [2] => "3.3 subcategory")))
```

I think it has something to do with group by + join

The query I've tryed

```
SELECT 
    categories.name, 
    subcategories.name
FROM categories     
INNER JOIN
    subcategories ON
    categories.id = subcategories.category  
GROUP BY categories.name
```

Comment: provide query that you were tried..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use 2 SQL statement and re-build array.

Comment: Yeah, i know how to do it, but unfortunately, i need a single query